# Trimming decimal point value in a floating value SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT dev_in AS LanguageDeveloped, AVG(dcost - scost) AS ProfitMargin 
FROM software 
GROUP BY dev_in
```

when I execute this code, the output is

```
LanguageDeveloped  ProfitMargin
basi               5600.0500000
c                  7500.7510000
pascal             4000.7500000
```

How can I trim the `ProfitMargin` values say `5600.0500000` to `5600.050` ?

`dcost` and `scost` are of `int` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rounding:

```
round(AVG(dcost - scost),2), 
cast(round(AVG(dcost - scost),2) as numeric(36,2))
```

Comment: the cast() worked. 36 meaning 36 digits before . right?

Comment: Had to look it up to confirm but yes....The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx